# How to use if/and?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to use if-function with "and". It doesn't work - is there a better way or a better command? Here is an example of my code:

```
        if measure >= 4.52 and <= 4.58:
            optimal += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
        elif measure >= 4.50 and <= 4.60:
            allowed += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
        else:
            faulty += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is already a perfect answer fo that. But you can skip ```and``` if you want ```elif 4.60>=measure >= 4.50 and ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to repeat `measure` in your `if` conditions.  Like so:

```py
        if measure >= 4.52 and measure <= 4.58:
            optimal += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
        elif measure >= 4.50 and measure <= 4.60:
            allowed += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
        else:
            faulty += measure
            total += measure
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't with the `if`, it's with the `and`.  Take the `if` out of the picture for a second:

```
>>> measure = 4.53
>>> measure >= 4.52 and <= 4.58
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    measure >= 4.52 and <= 4.58
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's invalid because `<= 4.58` on its own isn't a valid statement.

```
>>> measure >= 4.52 and measure <= 4.58
True
```

Now you have a valid boolean statement (produced by `and`ing two other boolean statements together) that you can use in an `if` statement:

```
>>> if measure >= 4.52 and measure <= 4.58:
...     print("success!")
... 
success!
```

If you want to check for a value being between two other values, you don't need an `and` at all; you can also combine inequality operators into a single statement like this:

```
>>> 4.52 <= measure <= 4.58
True
```